# MSBuild command line - cannot run rc.exe

Tags: windows, visual-c++, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

I have a  need to build a project from command line using msbuild. This has been working for years now, however after installing vs2022 it no longer works. I was previously using vs2019 msbuild command line with no problems. I have tried every combination of vs/toolset/winsdk I can think of but nothing works. If I compile from within vs there is zero issue.

But from command line I get (no matter the vs, toolset, winsdk version):

```
MSBuild version 17.9.5+33de0b227 for .NET Framework
Build started 15.02.2024 11:31:29 AM.

Project "C:\work_local\workspace\cpp\vs_issue\platform_tools_test.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "x64\Debug\".
  Creating directory "x64\Debug\platform.71e888c7.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "x64\Debug\platform.71e888c7.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
  Touching "x64\Debug\platform.71e888c7.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe /c /ZI /JMC /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagno
  stics:column /sdl /Od /D _DEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /permissive- /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /
  Zc:inline /Fo"x64\Debug\\" /Fd"x64\Debug\vc142.pdb" /external:W3 /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:queue platform_tools_test.cpp
  platform_tools_test.cpp
Link:
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\work_l
  ocal\workspace\cpp\vs_issue\x64\Debug\platform_tools_test.exe" /INCREMENTAL /ILK:"x64\Debug\platform_tools_test.ilk" /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32
  .lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC
  :"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\work_local\workspace\cpp\vs_issue\x64\Debug\platform_tools_test.pdb" /SUBS
  YSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:\work_local\workspace\cpp\vs_issue\x64\Debug\platform_tools_test.lib" /MACHINE:X64 x64\
  Debug\platform_tools_test.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe' [C:\work_local\workspace\cpp\vs_issue\platform_tools_test.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\work_local\workspace\cpp\vs_issue\platform_tools_test.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"C:\work_local\workspace\cpp\vs_issue\platform_tools_test.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
(Link target) ->
  LINK : fatal error LNK1158: cannot run 'rc.exe' [C:\work_local\workspace\cpp\vs_issue\platform_tools_test.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.10
```

I have tried all the hacks of copying the rc.exe + rcdll.dll from the winsdk folder to the same folder as the Link.exe. The only thing this changes is that it then has the full path of rc.exe in the LNK1158 message.

In an attempt of desperation I also tried to use CMake with a very basic setup and it cannot find the compiler.

```
C:\work_local\workspace\cpp\vs_issue\build>cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -T host=x64 -A x64 ..
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I've completely run out of ideas (short of setting up a VM with a clean windows environment and trying to reproduce my original setup).

I've tried uninstalling all VS versions, repairing the install. Any advice would be appreciated.

I've tried multiple versions of the windows sdk. Under all conditions rc.exe is in the path and accessible (after either using the VS developer console or running the vcvarsall.bat script) (ignore my attempt at running rce... fingers are faster than my brain)

[image: rc.exe accessibility]

The link and subsequent rc calls are as follows:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE /OUT:"C:\work_local\workspace\cpp\vs_issue\x64\Debug\platform_tools_test.exe" /INCREMENTAL /ILK:"x64\Debug\platform_tools_test.ilk" /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\work_local\workspace\cpp\vs_issue\x64\Debug\platform_tools_test.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /IMPLIB:"C:\work_local\workspace\cpp\vs_issue\x64\Debug\platform_tools_test.lib" /MACHINE:X64 x64\Debug\platform_tools_test.obj

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\rc.exe /nologo /x /fo "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\lnk{EC0E3243-FF9A-4248-B473-A81E49E339C9}.tmp" "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Temp\lnk{887BFFEF-FF37-4E78-8CB2-3AEE0C2DB4DF}.tmp"
```

Comment: What error message do you get if you just run rc.exe by itself?

Comment: There's no error when running rc.exe. I tried to figure out the parameters that the build system was trying to pass to rc.exe, but even turning on -v:diag to msbuild didn't give the rc command, just the link command

Comment: When you build at the command line, are you using a "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022" or an equivalent where the VS2022 version of VsDevCmd.bat has been run to set up the PATH and environment?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with both the Developer Command prompt from the start menu, as well as running the vcvarsall.bat file. All situations give the same issue.

Comment: In the VS2022 installer have you installed one of the Windows SDKs, e.g. `Windows 11 SDK (10.0.22621.0)`? On my system `rc` is installed as part of the SDK. My `PATH` in a dev cmd includes the directory of the SDK.

Comment: Yes, I've tried with multiple versions of Windows SDK. I've updated the question to show that rc.exe is accessible and can be executed

Comment: While this post is for an older version of Visual Studio, have you tried any of the answers  in it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372706/visual-studio-cant-build-due-to-rc-exe

Comment: Can you successfully build a Desktop Application (.exe) generated by the Windows Desktop Wizard project template? That particular project type includes a .rc file that gets compiled with rc.exe. 

Some additional tools to help tshoot this would SysInteras ProcMon which can tell you exactly how the rc.exe is being launched. 

Alternatively, if you can repro the issue via running msbuild ufrom a command prompt, add /bl to the msbuild commandline and use the structured log viewer  https://msbuildlog.com , to see how rc.exe is being invoked.

Comment: TimothyG, I have tried these options and they do not resolve the issue. The winsdk folder is on the path.

@EdDore, I have updated the post with the link and rc.exe call.

Comment: @EdDore trying to build a blank windows desktop project gives an odd error:
TRACKER : error TRK0002: Failed to execute command: ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\rc.exe" /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /l0x0409 /nologo /foWindowsProject1\x64
\Debug\WindowsProject1.res WindowsProject1.rc". The operation completed successfully. [C:\work_local\workspace\cpp\desktop_proj\WindowsProject1\WindowsProject1.vcxproj]

From within VS the project builds no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've resolved this issue. It is my organizations aggressive virus scanner.

One thing that clued me in (thank you @EdDore) was watching the procmon dumps while building. As soon as the rc.exe started the virus scanner process all of a sudden went crazy.

After some searching I came across this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65306958/4375845

The virus scanner really does not like the tracker app. So it basically kills it and drops all file that were handled by it.

By setting `/p:TrackFileAccess=false` to the msbuild command (or setting `set(CMAKE_VS_GLOBALS "TrackFileAccess=false")` for cmake processes). This appears to resolve the issue.

Of course you then lose incremental building. For my case, I don't care.

I imagine this does not come up when VS builds because the VS process is whitelisted (my guess, but dealing with corporate infrastructure is a nightmare).

Comment: Good ole organization virus scanners strike again.  We've had some fun with those too, in particular around docker

Comment: I understand the need for them, especially for non-IT based users... but PLEASE have some way to tell me you blocked something.